# Make prediction with saved Tensorflow Estimator in Tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-estimator

The model I am using is `tf.estimator.BoostedTreesClassifier` . I was able to save the model using the following code:

```
feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key=key) for key in x_train.keys()]
feature_spec = tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feature_columns)

# Build receiver function, and export.
serving_input_receiver_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec)

model.export_saved_model('model', serving_input_receiver_fn)
```

After saving the model I am able to load it:

```
loaded = tf.saved_model.load('/model/...')
print(list(loaded.signatures.keys()))  
infer = loaded.signatures["serving_default"]
```

At this point my question is how can I use `infer` to make predictions? My test dataset is pd.Dataframe like this one:

```
     feat1    feat2   feat3
0     0.1      0.5     0.9
1      .        .       .
2      .        .       .
3      .        .       .
4     0.9      0.9     0.1
```

What is the syntax that I need to use to forward my test dataset into `infer` to make the predictions.
Thanks

Comment: With the predict API? Passing the test dataset similarly to the training.  https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/BoostedTreesClassifier#predict

Comment: The predict API it is working but can't be used once I restore my saved model. https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model .The problem is that once you save and then load the model, you will have to use the imported signatures to make predictions. In my code it is the `infer` variable